# array required, but java.lang.String found Java Class Array Error

Tags: java, arrays, object, instance

I'm getting the following error:

```
array required, but java.lang.String found
```

and I'm not sure why.

What I'm trying to do is put an instance of an object (I believe that is correct terminology), into an array of that type of class (of the object).

I have the class:

```
public class Player{
     public Player(int i){
           //somecodehere
     }
}
```

then in my main method I create an instance of it:

```
static final Player[] a = new Player[5]; // this is where I'm trying to create the array.
public static void main(String[] args){
     Player p = new Player(1);
     a[0] = p; //this is the line that throws the error
}
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: You are not showing us the code that is throwing the exception. This code is fine.

Comment: provide us with the code that exception happened!

Comment: Just save and recompile.

Comment: Try stepping through your code in a debugger to identify the exact line that is failing and what the relevant variables are at the time.

Comment: Is this a compile-time error or a run-time exception? The message reads like a compile-time problem.

Comment: This should run fine. Try what @SotiriosDelimanolis said.

Comment: Do you have a `clean` target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, the only way I see for that error to happen is if you actually had

```
static final Player[] a = new Player[5]; // this is where I'm trying to create the array.
public static void main(String[] args){
    String a = "...";
    Player p = new Player(1);
    a[0] = p; //this is the line that throws the error
}
```

In this case, your local variable `a` would shadow the `static` variable of the same name. The array access expression

```
a[0]
```

would therefore cause a compilation error like

```
Foo.java:13: error: array required, but String found
                a[0] = p; // this is the line that throws the error
```

since `a` is not an array, but the `[]` notation only works for array types.

You probably just need to save and recompile.

Comment: That was actually very impressive. It was a problem with my keyboard, I did have another local variable. Thank you!

Comment: @user1530491 how come keyboard can cause this problem? :o